# iOS: Add date picker programmatically and center it within its cell

Tags: ios, autolayout

To save performance I'm creating the date picker only once in my app via a Singleton class and want to add the date picker then programmatically. This works, however I don't really know how to set the constraints in order to center the Date picker within its cell. This is my code:

```
//Inserting and aligning the date picker
    self.datePicker = [[Singletons sharedManager] datePicker];
    [self.datePickerCell addSubview:self.datePicker];
    // Width constraint, half of parent view width
    [self.datePickerCell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.datePicker
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.datePickerCell
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:0.5
                                                           constant:0]];

    // Height constraint, half of parent view height
    [self.datePickerCell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.datePicker
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.datePickerCell
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         multiplier:0.5
                                                           constant:0]];

    // Center horizontally
    [self.datePickerCell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.datePicker
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.datePickerCell
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    // Center vertically
    [self.datePickerCell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.datePicker
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.datePickerCell
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: So what *does* happen? How about a screenshot?

Comment: Nothing happens. On the iPhone it's centered anyway because of the smaller size of the cell. But on the iPad its at the complete left of the cell and as small as the standard size of the picker.